# What type of tube does this fitting take?

Tags: electrical, lighting, kitchens, uk

It is a UK 240v kitchen fitting, I know the tube needs to be about 600mm long, but I don’t know if it needs a T4, T8 or whatever type.

(The old tenant removed the tube and did not replace it, so I could not look at the old tube!   The property is a 2hr drive from me, so I can’t just remove the fitting and take it into a shop.)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Unplug the fixture or turn off the circuit, unscrew the screw that is visible and its related screw(s), read the information on the ballast (which should be inside the area the screw gives access to.)

Comment: That will take me 4hrs of driving, as I can't expect the new tenant to do it.

Comment: ..the joys of being an absentee landlord. Developing a relationship with a more-local-to-the-rental maintenance service might be worthwhile.

Comment: I may have to do that, it will cost me a call out charge and the new tenant may have to take time of work.   Unlike just posting them a new tube.

Comment: I suppose you might post them a selection of tubes in the right length and see what works...get more precise measurements first, if you can ask that of the tenant. Diameter on the pin circle  (or just the same picture with a ruler in it) as well as length.